# last-of-type with anchor tag not working in CSS

Tags: css

Why does the css styling meant for the last-of-type get administered on the `<a>` tag ?

And how do I make the last `.block` have `margin-right: 3em` and `<a>` tag element have `margin-right: 1em` ?

```css
.wrapper {
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: silver;
}
.block {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: teal;
    line-height: 2;
    margin-right: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.block:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 3em;
}
.end {
    line-height: 2;
    width: 3em;
    height: 2em;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="block">A</a>
    <div class="block">A</div>
    <div class="block">A</div>
    <div class="block">A</div>
    <div class="end">End</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To apply the 3em margin, just margin left on the end element (last-child works too) and for the anchor margin, just put it on the anchor (first-child works too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because `a` is last of it's type of a tag for it's parent.

In other words, the selector `.element:last-of-type` does not select the last element with a class of `.element`. Rather, it selects an element which has an `.element` class applied **AND** is simultaneously last of it's type among the siblings.

Consider the following example:

```css
.element,
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.element:last-of-type {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- is last of type "p" AND has ".element" 
       class applied - will be matched -->
  <p class="element"></p>
  <span class="element"></span>
  <span class="element"></span>
  
  <!-- last of type "span" and has ".element" 
       class applied - will be matched -->
  <span class="element"></span>

  <!-- last of type, but does NOT have an ".element" 
       class applied - will NOT be matched -->
  <a class="square"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's strange. I didn't say `a:last-of-type`, I said `.block:last-of-type`.

Comment: @KayaToast that selector does not work with class, it works with nodes, in the answer above, the class element does absolutely nothing, it would work the exact same without it. I also don't see how the above answers your actual question

Comment: Can you post an answer to the question instead of just pointing out the issue